# How to request complete url (not default) in spring boot and print response

Tags: spring-boot

How can I hit a GET request on a localhost URL other than the embedded tomcat's and print the response in the console?

Comment: spring need an application server. If not tomcat, which one do you want to use ?

Comment: explain the question with some examples

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and get your first badge. Create a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for clarity.

Comment: Need a solution to hit a server URL that is hosted somewhere (not default tomcat) which will give some JSON response. Print that response in application logs or console.